# Algorithm to find the rotational degrees of a point according to some function

Tags: functions, algorithms, graphing-functions

Hi I'm developing a game. In this game you can fire a missile, the path of the missile is given accord some function. For example if the function is f(x)=x^2 the missile should look like this.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there some way to get the rotation degrees given a (x,y) point and the distance from the x axis?
I thought that this was a very common algorithm, but I didnt find any info about it. Any tip will be appreciated

Comment: Do you have the distance from the $y$-axis, i.e. the $x$ value? You see, if you have a distance from $x$-axis $=2.5$, your missile can be either pointing up or pointing down!

Comment: Perhaps you have heard about [derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) or maybe [gradients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient)?

Comment: @peterwhy Yes I have both. My algorithm is pretty basic, evaluates the function for every point in the x axis (the width of the screen) and then draws the point in the coordinate (x;f(x)). I need more than know if the missile should point to the top or the bottom I need know the degrees that I must rotate the picture.

Comment: @dtldarek No I did not hear about derivatives nor gradients, my maths are pretty basic and I thought that will be better ask some experts rather than  start looking in the math books just for one algorithm ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "the rotation degrees"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson For example, if I know that the original position of the missile's picture is vertical (like this one [example pic](http://preview.turbosquid.com/Preview/Content_2009_07_13__19_31_08/Sm2Main400-400.jpgc6d9171d-6c10-4285-a7b2-349e7105add4Larger.jpg)). Given a point (x;f(x)) how much degrees I must rotate the picture in some sense (clock-wise or not) to show it like in the example pictures that I put above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, let $\varepsilon$ be some very, very small positive number (the smaller the better, but you need to be careful to avoid numerical errors).

In case your $f$ depends only on $x$ (e.g. $f(x) = x^2$ would be your parabola), then points $(x,f(x))$ and $(x+\varepsilon, f(x+\varepsilon))$ represent a segment which direction approximately agrees with what you want to find.

The smaller the $\varepsilon$, the better the approximation. In fact with the limit $\varepsilon \to 0$ you get the actual value, and this similar to how the [derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of $f$ is defined for functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(x+\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}.$$

Assuming that your $f$ depends on time (e.g. $f(t) = (t,t^2)$ would generate your parabola), then points $f(t)$ and $f(t+\varepsilon)$ are the endings of aforementioned segment. Observe that here $f$ is $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. its values are points. If you were to perform an operation analogous to the above one on each coordinate, you would get something called a [Jacobian of a function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).

To calculate the angle use the inverse function to tangent, namely [arctangent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctangent), or even better its sugared version [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Works like a charm, as you said I only need: rotationAngle = atan2(f(currentX+gap)-f(currentX),(currentX+gap)-(currentX)).